# blit_buffer function closes Kivy app without any warning

Tags: python, image, opencv, kivy, ros

I'd like to convert the ROS sensor image to the Kivy texture. But blit_buffer closes the app without any message. I checked that the color format of sensor_msg is bgr8. I don't know what the problem is because there is no error message.

```
def convert_to_texture(self, sensor_msg):
    cv_image = CvBridge().imgmsg_to_cv2(sensor_msg, "bgr8")
    resized_image = cv2.resize(cv_image, (900, 450))

    buf = cv2.flip(resized_image, 0).tostring()

    texture = Texture.create(size=(resized_image.shape[1], resized_image.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr")
    texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this before. I believe the `texture.blit_buffer()` must be done on the main thread. I haven't found any documentation that says so, but that has been my experience. Try something like this:

```
def convert_to_texture(self, sensor_msg):
    cv_image = CvBridge().imgmsg_to_cv2(sensor_msg, "bgr8")
    resized_image = cv2.resize(cv_image, (900, 450))

    buf = cv2.flip(resized_image, 0).tostring()

    texture = Texture.create(size=(resized_image.shape[1], resized_image.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr")
    # texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.updateTexture, texture, buf))

    def updateTexture(self, texture, buf, *args):
        texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
```